# What is the easiest way to insert data in MySQL using a ruby script

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, mysql2

I did a ruby script that parses a lot of files in ruby data structures, like hashes for example.

I need to insert all this data in a MySQL database.

What I found:

[mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)

[tmtm](http://www.tmtm.org/en/ruby/mysql/)

[dbi](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm)

Is there some native way to do this?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

Lets say that I have a hash with 100 entries like this:

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2 ..., "c" => 100}
```

I would like to create a table at mysql with all this columns. I am afraid of Active Record is gonna be hard to do that.

PS: Im not using Rails, just a simple ruby script

Comment: Well ActiveRecord is the obvious answer, but I'm not sure why it wasn't to you?

Comment: I was thinking in don't use ORM for this. I prefer to use pure SQL. But I'm going to try active records for while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would prefer ActiveRecord, because I don't have to clutter my code with lots of SQL statements.  Besides activerecord makes life easier.

Set it up like this

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( 
 :adapter => "mysql2",
 :host => "host",
 :username=>"user",
 :password=>"user",
 :database => "your_db"
)
```

Then use tables like this

```
class SingularTableName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :table_relationship
end
```

Then query like this

```
SingularTableName.all #=> all records
SingularTableName.first #=> first record
SingularTableName.where("query")
SingularTableName.create("...) #=> create a record/row
```

You can find more methods here => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

**Update:**

To overcome plural table names and default primary key, you can use

```
class AnyName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'your table name'
  self.primary_key = 'your primary key'
  ...
end
```

Comment: All the example that I have found are using Rails. Can you please help me with some example using a table using some fields. Its not necessary use relationship. Just insert data.

Comment: Works. I had some problems like using column called `type` cause something reserved to use as inheritance stuff. Anyway.. thanks dude

Comment: ...and pluralization. =)